# How do you communicate with an Elixir Agent from within a Phoenix Controller?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

It's great to be learning a language early enough in its life when the language's creator answers your questions! Well, my question is - how do you communicate with an Agent from within a Phoenix controller method? I've got this in hello_blockchain/monitor.ex:

```
defmodule HelloBlockchain.Monitor do
  def start_link do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end)
  end

  def put(pid, key, value) do
    Agent.update(pid, &Map.put(&1, key, value))
  end

  def get(pid, key) do
    Agent.get(pid, &Map.get(&1, key))
  end
end
```

and in my hello_blockchain_web/controllers/block_controller.ex, I want to save a value in a controller action (list), and retrieve it in the same action next time it's called. But I need the Agent's pid to do this. It seems I need to save it too. Or I could use a named Agent. But I'd need a way to save this name. It seems like a Catch-22. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

[`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html#content) documentation page starts with an example you might use as is. Basically: in Elixir you want to use *named* `GenServer`s to lookup them by `name` rather than by `pid`.

This approach has many advantages, e.g. `name` does not change when server restarts, while `pid` does.

So, you do the following:

```rb
defmodule HelloBlockchain.Monitor do
  use Agent

  def start_link do
    # __MODULE__ here would be HelloBlockchain.Monitor
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def put(key, value) do
    Agent.update(__MODULE__, &Map.put(&1, key, value))
  end

  def get(key) do
    Agent.get(__MODULE__, &Map.get(&1, key))
  end
end
```

And you are all set; `Agent.get(HelloBlockchain.Monitor, :foo)` will work from anywhere (assuming the `Agent` was indeed started and supervised.)

Apparently, you don’t need to save a name, you just give the name that is predefined and known. The common approach in Elixir is to use the name of the module this agent is nested within.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid reply. My problem now is how to "start and supervise" Monitor. My application.ex has                                               `def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    children = [
      supervisor(HelloBlockchainWeb.Endpoint, []),
      worker(HelloBlockchain.Monitor, [])
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: HelloBlockchain.Supervisor]
  end` but when I try to start the app I get `** (Mix) Could not start application hello_blockchain: HelloBlockchain.Application.start(:normal, []) returned a bad value:`

Comment: This comment is unreadable. Please post another question, since this issue has nothing to do with what was asked in the OP.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - code in comments doesn't format correctly.  I  needed to add   Supervisor.start_link(children, opts) to application.ex, function start/2 for the app to start. But Agent.get(HelloBlockchain.Monitor, :foo) causes (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Agent.get/3.

Comment: Got it. I had to call  foo = Monitor.get(:foo), and Monitor.put( :foo, "bar" ). Thanks so much, mudasobwa.